# How to get the value between dollar sign in string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to get the value between dollar sign in a string and put them in a list.

For example, here is a string:

```
var a ='Dear $name$, This is my number $number$. This is my address $address$ Thank you!'
```

and what I want to get is,

```
var b = '$name$,$number$,$address$'
```

Do I have to take care about the '$' in the string due to $ is also used in jQuery? Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far and what's not working in your attempts?

Comment: You want to be careful about `$` because it has special meaning in regular expressions. Nothing in the question, or the answers, has anything to do with jQuery. This is a plain-Javascript question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `match`:

```
a.match(/\$.*?\$/g);
```

This returns an array with all the values. You can also use

```
a.match(/\$.*?\$/g)||[];
```

to make sure that you’ve always got an array because if there’s no match you’ll get the `null` object which is not always useful.

The RegExp is also explained in an [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30027346/4642212) to a similar question: match anything (`.`), any number of times (`*`), as few times as possible (`?`).

Then you can use `join` to join that Array into a String:

```
(a.match(/\$.*?\$/g)||[]).join(',');
```

Code:

```
var a='Dear $name$, This is my number $number$. This is my address $address$ Thank you!';
var b=(a.match(/\$.*?\$/g)||[]).join(',');
```

Output:

> `"$name$,$number$,$address$"`

Effectively, in this case the regular expression matches every `$` followed by anything up to the next `$` and finally that dollar sign at the end. And `match` will give a list of results if you specify the `g` (global) flag at the end.

As this is a string (and the above a regular expression) literal, there’s no interference with jQuery’s `$` symbol. The only important thing is to escape that symbol with a backslash (`\$`) because it has a special meaning in RegExp.

Answer (score 0):

get matches with a regular expression:

```
var matches = a.match(/\$\w+\$/g);
```

returns an array of matches, so then just join on comma:

```
var b = matches.join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to split and slice. I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maniccomputer/5gvLhq2p/) to show how its done.

Here is the jQuery to accomplish what you want.

```
var a = 'Dear $name$, This is my number $number$. This is my address $address$ Thank you!';

var b = [];
var count = 0;

var split = a.split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    if (split[i].charAt(0) == "$") {
        b[count] = split[i].slice(0, $.inArray("$", split[i], 2)) + "$";
        count++;
    }
}
```