# Match any string between two different tokens

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a part of a string between two different tokens. They might be multiple occurrences of the tokens in a string.

Sample text (tokens are italic, text to match is bold):

> This is *[begin-match]* **a sample text** *[end-match]* with some
>   *[begin-match]* **tokens and normal** *[end-match]* text.

I have the following regex, which would work if the tokens were *{* and *}*:

```
/{([^}]+)}/g
```

I can't get this to work the **[begin-match]** and **[end-match]** tokens. It seems that the lack of negative lookbehind in Javascript is a big loss.

I can't figure out how to substitute the *{* and *}* for the tokens *[begin-match]* and *[end-match]*. How can I match on those?

Comment: You probably also need to know [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/x(.*?)y/g` where `x` is the beginning token and `y` the ending token.

This RegEx means: match anything (`.`), any number of times (`*`), as few times as possible (`?`).

A direct example from your question would be:

```
/\[begin-match\](.*?)\[end-match\]/g
```

The sample text is now in the first capturing group.

Answer (score 2):

```
\[begin-match\]((?:(?!\[end-match\]).)*)\[end-match\]
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/23

Comment: That's it :) Thanks! (I have to wait to accept your answer)

Comment: Instead of the `(?!...)` construction, you can use `(.*?)` to perform a non-greedy match: `\[begin-match\](.*?)\[end-match\]`

Comment: @robertklep That would be nearly identical to my answer.

Comment: Yeah, it is really over-complicated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclu and https://regex101.com/r/kE6eB2/1

Comment: @Xufox yes, it would :-) But showing how to escape brackets is also part of a solution.